# Swift SQLite database how to insert date field

Tags: swift, sqlite, date, insert

I have created Sqlite tables and I am trying to insert data. While inserting date field the compiler gives error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer!'

Here is my code:

```
func insert() {
    let db = openDatabase()
    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        let trNumber: String = scanOutput
        let empId: String = "TBD"
        let carrier = "TBD_CARRIER"
        let recLoc: String? = "TBD_LOCATION"
        let recDate: Date? = scannedDate
        let recdBy: String = "TBD_BUY"
        let dlyStatus: String? = "R"

        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, trNumber, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, empId, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, carrier, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, recLoc, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 5, recDate, -1, nil) // This line gives error
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 6, recdBy, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 7, dlyStatus, -1, nil)

// the code continues, but I have just reproduced the line where I get error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `sqlite3_bind_text` with a `Date` but that is for strings.

I suggest you save the `Date` as follows:

```
if let recDate = recDate {
    sqlite3_bind_double(insertStatement, someColumnIndex, recDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
} else {
    sqlite3_bind_null(insertStatement, someColumnIndex)
}
```

Then you can read it back with:

```
if sqlite3_column_type(queryStatement, someColumnIndex) != SQLITE_NULL {
    date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: sqlite3_column_double(queryStatement, someColumnIndex))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. I also added an optional binding to recDate to avoid crashing. So, when recDate is nil, can I insert " " (just double quotes signifying it is blank? - Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to deal with an optional date and NULL values in the database. Please don't forget to indicate your question has been successfully answered by accepting useful answers (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).

Comment: I printed the output. It shows date as Optional(2018-03-08 01:30:50 +0000). Is there a way to print without the "optional" and the parenthesis? Sorry I come from the world of Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: What output are you referring to? There are many existing discussions on how to properly deal with optionals in Swift. I suggest doing some reading in the Swift book and doing some searching on Stack Overflow for related questions. This is all beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am doing some research.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sqlite function datetime() in your insert statement

```
let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO Records (trNumber, empId, carrier, recLoc, recDate, recdBy, dlyStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,datetime(?),?,?)"
```

Then convert your Date to a String and bind it as text

```
// Setup date (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: recDate)

// Bind values to insert statement
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, (dateString as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
```

For reference, see https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/datetime.php